# Covariance in an urn model without replacement

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In an urn are $n$ marbles, $r$ of them are red and $b$ are blue. We draw $k<\min(r,b)$ marbles. Let $R$ be the number of drawn red marbels, and $B$ the number of blue marbles. I am looking for the Covariance of R and B.

I do know that $R$ and $B$ have hypergeometric distribution. However, i also know
$$R=\sum_{i=1}^k1_i^{(r)},\ \ \ B=\sum_{i=1}^k1_i^{(b)}$$
where $1_i^{(r)}$ are identically distributed but dependent random variables. They are also exchangable.

Now, the covariance should be
$$Cov(R,B)=\binom{k}{2}Cov(1^{(r)},1^{(b)}).$$

Further $\mathbb E(1^{(r)}1^{(b)})=\frac{rb}{n(n-1)}$ and $\mathbb E(1^{(r)})=\frac rn$ and $\mathbb E(1^{(b)})=\frac bn$. But
$$Cov(1^{(r)},1^{(b)})=\mathbb E(1^{(r)}1^{(b)})-\mathbb E(1^{(r)})\mathbb E(1^{(b)})=\frac{rb}{n^2(n-1)}.$$

However, this should be negativ. I do not see, why it is not.

Remark: I do know how to compute the correct answer using the random variables R and B. I am explicitly asking why my approach via indicator random variables gives the wrong sign.

EDIT: the real covariance is
$$Cov(R,B)=-k\cdot Var(1^{(r)})+2\binom{k}{2}Cov(1_i^{(r)},1_j^{(b)})$$
for an arbitrary choice of $i,j$ with $i\neq j$. This fixes the sign error.

Comment: You can't drop the $i$ index in the way that you've done. $\text{Cov}(1_i^{(r)}, 1_j^{(b)})$ will have one value when $i \ne j$ but a different value when $i = j$.

Comment: Right! But it's then just $-Var(1^{(r)}$. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compute $$\text{Cov}\Bigr(\sum_{i=1}^k 1_i^{(r)},\,  \sum_{j=1}^k 1_j^{(b)}\Bigr)=\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k \text{Cov}\Bigr(  1_i^{(r)},\,   1_j^{(b)}\Bigr) \,.$$
The number of summands is $k^2$, not ${k \choose 2}$.

You computed correctly the $k(k-1)$ summands corresponding to $i \ne j$,
but there are $k$ negative summands you omitted corresponding to $i=j$. Since marble $i$ is either red or blue, $E(1_i^{(r)}\cdot 1_i^{(b)})=0$, so
$$\text{Cov}\Bigr(  1_i^{(r)},\,   1_i^{(b)}\Bigr)=-\frac rn \frac bn \,.$$

When you add those you will get
$$\text{Cov}(R,B)=\frac{krb}{n^2}\cdot \Bigl(\frac{k-1}{n-1}-1\Bigr)\,.$$